# Generative Adverserial Networks - Training procedure

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently researching GAN's and I am having a little bit of trouble in understanding the so called "minimax" game which Generator and Discriminator are playing.

I would like to understand the math behind it and also why does gradiant saturate, and what does saturating gradiant mean, when Generator is trying to minimize the likelihood of Discriminator being right. I would appreciate any kind of resources and any kind of help which you can offer.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00160) paper. Also, the associated video. Ofcourse, the pre-requisite knowledge needed to understand it is a lot.. but there are always blog posts about every related topic.

Comment: Thank you ! I have not read this paper, but i sure will now! Once again, thanks!